# Carriage returns in file when passed as argument to program

Tags: python, arguments, temporary-files, carriage-return

I've got a python program that acts as a thin wrapper to an existing command line tool. If you've ever heard of globus, its a file service. To massively oversimplify things, there are various endpoints files can be located on. In order to "download" files to a local computer, you would create your own endpoint and transfer files to it. They have a command line tool that's pretty intuitive. The globus command line interface already allows for batch downloading. You would either pass as an argument the name of a file (where each line in the file contains 2 arguments, the path to the resource on the source endpoint, and the location you want it to be installed on the local endpoint) or using an additional optional argument, you can opt to pass in each of those lines into the cli one at a time until some EOF is reached.

For my work, we accept similar files to the ones used by globus. I perform a number of modifications. I then create my own temporary file, and then give THAT temporary file to globus using a subprocess.popen.

The problem is, while everythings works fine on linux, (and actually, 90% of the time, everything works perfect on windows too), on some specific usages in windows, I get an error.

My transfer will start, but I'll check on its status (which is done through the globus website) and I'll see that there was an error. The error globus is reporting looks to be a carriage return. This was strange given that I thought I had filtered out any carriage returns in my modification of our users data. But after a thorough double check, I see that when I was writing each line to a file, windows style line endings were being added.

No problem, I just added like 5 lines of code where I reopen the temp file in binary mode, read its contents, swap any \r's for \n's. Checked again, and awesome, there's no carriage returns.

however, when I call globus again, low and behold, I'm getting the carriage return error. I am at my wits end.

I've tried changing from the pyton tempfile module to doing manual creation and deletion of files in case there was anything hinky in that module. I've printed out the contents of the tempfile for the case that is giving me issues, and taken that exact file, and run the globus command manually and it works! So the file that's being generated is correct. Somehow, when getting passed as an argument to globus, there's something going on with the line endings.

I cannot figure out how if my script generates a file, and then I manually call globus with it, it works, but when I call globus in my script with the exact same file, its getting carriage return errors. I looked at the globus documentation to see if there's any arguments for this. nada.

I'm going to share with you the globus command in full, followed by a deidentified version of the relevant portion of my code.

I really hope you can help. I've been struggling with this for like 72 hours now.

Globus command:

`globus transfer $sourceEndpointID $destinationEndpointID --batch filename.txt`

and then the code is:

```
def my_function(mylist, my_id, local_id, args):
    temp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w+b', delete=False)
    for each in mylist:
        is_directory = False
        destination = args.destination.replace("\\", "/")
        if each["smallpath"] == "/":
            full_path = each["smallpath"] + "/"
        else:
            full_path = each["rel_path"].replace("\\", "/") + "/" + each["specific_path"].lstrip("/")
        if os.path.basename(full_path) == "":
            is_directory = True
        if is_directory is False:
            line = f'"{full_path}" "~/{destination}/{each["orgID"]}-{each["userID"]}/{os.path.basename(full_path)}" \n'
        else:
            if each["smallpath"] != "/":
                slash_index = full_path.rstrip('/').rfind("/")
                local_dir = full_path[slash_index:].rstrip().rstrip('/')
            else:
                local_dir = "/"
            line = f'"{full_path}" "~/{destination}/{each["orgID"]}-{each["userID"]}/{local_dir.lstrip("/")}" --recursive \n'
        line = line.replace("\\", "/")
        temp.write(line)
    temp.seek(0)
    windows_ending = b'\r'
    unix_ending = b'\n'
    double_newline = b'\n\n'
    with open(temp.name, 'rb') as file:
        file_contents = file.read()
    temp.seek(0)
    file_contents = file_contents.replace(windows_ending, unix_ending)
    file_contents = file_contents.replace(double_newline, unix_ending)
    with open(temp.name, 'wb') as file:
        file.write(file_contents)
    myprocess = subprocess.Popen(["programname", "commandname", myid, local_id, "--batch",
                                                temp.name], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    mycommand = myprocess.communicate()[0].decode('utf-8')
    temp.close()
    os.unlink(temp.name)
```

Comment: Why does your code call Popen with "programname" and "commandname" instead of "globus" and "transfer"? Have you tried creating a minimal script which only calls globus one the known-to-work file, without the pre-processing beforehand? Does that work?

Comment: It does work. Apologies, I copied the code from an email to a colleague where I was trying to obfuscate the specifics about the program, thus the "program name" and "commandname".  But yes I have taken the temp file created by my program and directly run it with globus and it works. It only doesn't the weird carriage return when I do it through my script

Comment: I still do not quite get it, so let me ask you a couple of potentially dumb questions: What ist the difference between the "program" and the "script"? You state that the file is created by your "program", but that it fails when you use your "script". To me, it looks like the function presented above does both things, writing the file and calling globus. So do I see it correctly that the "program" basically is the function presented above? And that you run the function, the creation succeeds, but the Popen fails? And that globus works via command line, but not via python Popen?